# Fastapi get_current_user dependency doesn't work

Tags: api, session, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Please help me, I have no idea what is wrong - my get_current_user dependency throws an 422 Unprocessable entity errror.

I am working on authorization and database connection in my project.

I am trying to create a get_user_me endpoint, which will get and return current user.

```py
@router.get("/me")
def get_user_me(current_user = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return current_user
```

get_current_user dependency should return current user, but it throws HTTP422 (Unprocesable entity).

```py
def get_current_user(db: Session = Depends(get_db), token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"}
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if not username:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user_by_username(db, token_data.username)
    if not user:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

Everything works fine until the return. The user is a correct model, but when I step over in the debugger (it should go back to the endpoint) it redirects me to closing my localsession (db.close):

```py
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try: 
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I am working with debugger, and in the last line (return user) the user is just a normal model.

```
>>>user
<src.models.users.User object at 0x0000023B377A14E0>
>>>user.id
0
>>>user.username
'olekniemirka'
```

Response body I get in the api docs:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "user_id"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid integer",
      "type": "type_error.integer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Logs I get in the terminal:

```bash
INFO:     Started server process [12012]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2022-11-29 20:45:55,319 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select pg_catalog.version()
2022-11-29 20:45:55,320 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2022-11-29 20:45:55,322 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select current_schema()
2022-11-29 20:45:55,322 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2022-11-29 20:45:55,322 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2022-11-29 20:45:55,323 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2022-11-29 20:45:55,324 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-11-29 20:45:55,329 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.id, users.username, users.name, users.surname, users.email, users.hashed_password
FROM users
WHERE users.username = %(username_1)s
2022-11-29 20:45:55,329 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00062s] {'username_1': 'olekniemirka'}
2022-11-29 20:51:20,858 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49643 - "GET /users/me HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

I don't get why, but get_user works just fine (it also uses get_current_user dependency), but the current user is not used anywhere.

It's like the assignment of user to the current_user in my first endpoint is breaking the app.

```py
@router.get("/{user_id}", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def get_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user: models.User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    user = crud.get_user(db, user_id)
    return user

# crud get user
def get_user(db: Session, id: int):
    stmt = select(models.User).where(models.User.id == id)
    user = db.scalar(stmt)
    return user
```

Comment: You're trying to retrieve `/users/me`, but have defined `user_id` to be `int`. In that case you're trying to coerce `me` into an integer, and FastAPI is telling you that "no, the value you're giving for `user_id` is not an integer". The 422 error is related to that issue, not current_user. Since your `/{user_id}` endpoint was registered first, that takes precedence over the `/me` endpoint.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you, you are right! Hmm I thought having every user endpoint under /user/ tag would be the nicest, is there any correct way to name those endpoints?

Comment: Register `/me` first, then register the `/{user_id}` endpoint after that - the first matching endpoint will be the one selected, so `/me` will be attempted to match first, then the other, general endpoint will be invoked if the requested url isn't `/me` (i.e. /1 or /2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Config class from my pydantic model solved the problem for some reason, but it is a very ugly  solution.

```
class Config:
    orm_mode=True
```

**EDIT**:

Answer which solved the question by @MatsLindh

You're trying to retrieve /users/me, but have defined user_id to be int. In that case you're trying to coerce me into an integer, and FastAPI is telling you that "no, the value you're giving for user_id is not an integer". The 422 error is related to that issue, not current_user. Since your /{user_id} endpoint was registered first, that takes precedence over the /me endpoint.

Comment: Can you please explain how using "orm_mode=True" is ugly?

Comment: I meant that deleting it is ugly.